# Setting up a subdomain to use both www and non-www

Tags: dns

I have `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` both working. Now, the subdomain `sub.mydomain.com` also works well; **but not** `www.sub.mydomain.com`.

1. I've tried adding A records for for `www.app`; but not working.
2. I've also tried creating a CNAME record "www.app" for `mydomain.com`; but also not working.

Browser throws a *NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID* for both.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: www.sub.mydomain.com is not supposed to work. Can you think of a single example domain that works like that?

Comment: I'm not sure... You're saying www would not typically go on subdomains? I never really noticed before.

Comment: "You're saying www would not typically go on subdomains?" Yes

Comment: You're right... I'm an idiot. Just checked out a few other websites. I had never noticed this before lol Cheers mate!